# How to Order String Array by Number

Tags: processing

So I have an array of strings

```
String [] scoreboard = {"AAA - 100", "BBB - 0", "CCC - 200"};
```

I was wondering how to order these so that the biggest number is at the top and the smallest is at the bottom and then print each one on the screen like so:

```
CCC - 200
AAA - 100
BBB - 0
```

So far I have my code like this:

```
float ty = height - height/1.25;
for (int i = 0; i < scoreboard.length; i++) {
  text(scoreboard[i], width/2, ty);
  ty += 60;
}
```

Right now this prints out them in order they are in the string, I am struggling to sort them. I have tried many different methods but not quite what I want.

Comment: Oh, I just found you can just combine sort() and reverse() by sorting them in ascending order and reversing it.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine `sort()` and `reverse()` together by sorting them into ascending order and reverse it.

```
String [] scoreboard = {"AAA - 100", "BBB - 0", "CCC - 200"};

scoreboard = reverse(sort(scoreboard));
```

Comment: Won't this sort them into reverse-alphabetical order? The OP wants to sort them by the numbers in the strings.

Comment: Sorry, I just realized you were OP. But in any case, won't this sort it into CCC, BBB, AAA order? And don't you want CCC, AAA, BBB order, based on their scores?

Comment: Nope, I tried it with all sorts of string and numbers and it still sorted the numbers for me.

Comment: That doesn't make sense to me. When I run your code and then call `println(scoreboard)`, I see that it's sorted into CCC, BBB, AAA.

Comment: Weird, maybe because I'm using processing, idk

Comment: I'm using Processing too. My guess is your data happens to have the same reverse alphabetical order as it does numeric order. If you encounter issues in the future, my answer might help you out. :p

Comment: Weird I just did another test with multiple string and numbers and it didn't work yet earlier worked fine.

Comment: Yeah, my guess is you had something like `"AAA - 0", "BBB - 100", "CCC - 200"` where reverse alphabetical sort was coincidentally the same as reverse numeric sort. If you have something like `"AAA - 100", "BBB- 0", "CCC - 200"` then they won't be the same, and you'll need a custom sort.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I'd consider creating a class that contained both a `name` and a `score` variable, instead of working with strings that you have to parse.

Either way, whether you're using `String` values or a custom class, I would google something like "java sort array" for a ton of results.

Basically, you're going to want to call `Arrays.sort()` function and pass in a custom `Comparator` to do the sorting based on the number value, either in your custom class or in your string.

Here's a very basic example:

```
MyClass[] myArray = // create array
Arrays.sort(myArray, new Comparator<MyClass>(){
  public int compare(MyClass one, MyClass two){
    return two.score.compareTo(one.score);
  }
});
```

This approach assumes you have a class named `MyClass` that contains an `Integer` `score` variable. If you stick with `String` values, then your `compare()` function will have to parse the number out of the `String` and compare those.

Comment: This is kind of confusing. I need to create a class with an integer and string? As well as a new array of that class?

Comment: @TheWelshManc You don't **have** to, but it's what I would do. Right now you're putting two types of data in a string, which I would say is an [anti-pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-pattern). But even if you want to stick with using a string, you still need a custom `Comparator` to sort them based on the numbers inside them.

Comment: I get the string of scores from a text file that saves after every game so I have an array that loads from the file. Not sure how to do this with your method.

Comment: @TheWelshManc Which part are you confused about? For more info, I'd also recommend googling "java comparator" for a ton of results.

Comment: Well I'm using loadStrings which means I have to use an array, I call it scoreboard which contains both letters and numbers. I've tried looking through examples and can't seem to figure this one out. I did a lot of this last year at university but forgot a load of it.

Comment: @TheWelshManc You could use `loadStrings()` to load the strings, and then parse each line to create a class. But you don't have to do that. You can use my approach to sort string values. Just substitute `String` wherever `MyClass` is used in my example, and then change the logic to parse the string to get the numeric value out of it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178766/discussion-between-thewelshmanc-and-kevin-workman).